# What is "Manual Package Selection" in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, package-management, aptitude, debian-installer

What does choosing "Manual Package Selection" allow me to do, versus choosing one of the other options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-from-cd.html), under *Package Tasks*:

**Manually select packages**: Executes `aptitude` allowing you to individually select packages.

(Aptitude is a Text-User-Interface for package administration)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for the updated link
[Ubuntu Server Guide » Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-from-cd.html)
.

This link is for all *LTS* releases.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04.04 it seems to do nothing. After choosing this option the system starts installation and then reboots without ever giving a choice for individual packages.